# Call ajax while searching on select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select2 components and I want to bind a keyup event while searching. How can I bind to a specific element?

The only thing which works is the following, but this fires on both select2 items

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) { 
  // ajax call to get more product codes
});
```

My cshtml which contains the select items:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CatalogueCode", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control" })     
@Html.DropDownList("ProductCode", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `.` or `#` prefix from this selector: `'select2-search__field'`

Comment: use `:first-child` or `:nth-child()` after selector name

Comment: With '.select2-search__field:nth-child(2)' I have the same problem. It fires in both selects because search__field input appears only when i click inside the select.

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with the way select2 constructs html code. A class must be added to DropdownList with the following way:

```
 $("#ProductCode").select2({
        dropdownCssClass: "productCodesClass"
    });
```

Then if we want to take the value user wrote inside search field the following code is right.

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.productCodesClass > span.select2-search> input.select2-search__field', function (e) { 
            // ajax call to get more product codes
            // $(this).val() is user's input
        });
```